# Can't access QAbstractListModel data in ListView

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qabstractlistmodel

I have `Foo` class which is derived from `QAbstractListModel`. And `Bar` class which I register and create in qml. Bar class holds `Foo` object exposed as property.

```
class Foo : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Foo(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QAbstractListModel(parent) {
        mList.append("test1");
        mList.append("test2");
        mList.append("test3");
    }

    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        return mList.count();
    }
    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        return mList.at(index.row());
    }
private:
    QStringList mList;
};

class Bar : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Foo* foo READ foo NOTIFY fooChanged)

public:
    explicit Bar(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr)
        : QQuickItem(parent) {
        mFoo = new Foo(this);
    }

    Foo *foo() const { return mFoo; }

signals:
    void fooChanged(Foo *foo);

private:
    Foo *mFoo;
};
```

Register `Bar` type:

```
qmlRegisterType<Bar>("Custom", 1, 0, "Bar");
```

qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import Custom 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListView {
        id: someList
        model: bar.foo
        delegate: Text {
            text: modelData
        }
    }

    Bar {
        id: bar
    }
}
```

I create ListView and assign model `Foo`.
Expected result is to see delegate text filled with "test1", "test2", "test3" but I get this:

```
ReferenceError: modelData is not defined
ReferenceError: modelData is not defined
ReferenceError: modelData is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QML engine is right, `modelData` is not defined. Within a delegate, `model` is defined not `modelData`.

Also since in your `QAbstractListModel` you've not defined your own *roles*, you can use default *roles*. `display` is a default role you can use it. So, your `ListView` should look like this:

```
ListView {
    id: someList
    model: bar.foo
    delegate: Text {
        text: model.display
    }
}
```

- detailed information: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html